# Clip-path, how to create a circular progress bar?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I have seen a lot of solutions to creating a circular progress bars. They all seem to be extremely long and convoluted. I would like to create a very simple one, just by drawing two circles on top of each other and clipping a portion of the outter one, in order to create an appearance of a progress bar at less than 100%.

My HTML

```
    <div class="outter">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.outter {
  background-color: #08a1db;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  background-color: white;
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -42px 0 0 -42px;
}
```

Now the part I am having trouble with is using clip-path. I can't figure out, from the documentation, how to clip the outter circle and create that effect of the progress bar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clip css operator is marked as *deprecated* and being replaced by *clip-path* which in turn is not fully supported by **IE**.

Using clip,

```css
.progress-circle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
  padding: 0;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #F2E9E1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.35em;
  left: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4.3em;
  height: 4.3em;
  background-color: white;
  content: " ";
}


/* Text inside the control */

.progress-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #08a1db;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-half-clipper {
  /* a round circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* needed for clipping */
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  /* clips the whole left half*/
}


/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/

.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.value-bar {
  /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.45em solid #08a1db;
  /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
  /*background-color: #4D642D;*/
  /* for debug */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */

.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
  /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  background-color: #08a1db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar {
  display: none;
}


/* Progress bar rotation position */

.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(11deg);
}

.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}

.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(22deg);
}

.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(29deg);
}

.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(32deg);
}

.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(43deg);
}

.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(47deg);
}

.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(58deg);
}

.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(61deg);
}

.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(68deg);
}

.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(79deg);
}

.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(83deg);
}

.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(86deg);
}

.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(94deg);
}

.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(97deg);
}

.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(101deg);
}

.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(104deg);
}

.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(112deg);
}

.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(115deg);
}

.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(119deg);
}

.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(122deg);
}

.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}

.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
}

.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(137deg);
}

.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}

.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(148deg);
}

.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(151deg);
}

.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(155deg);
}

.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(158deg);
}

.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}

.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(166deg);
}

.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(169deg);
}

.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(173deg);
}

.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(176deg);
}

.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(184deg);
}

.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(187deg);
}

.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(191deg);
}

.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(194deg);
}

.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(198deg);
}

.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(202deg);
}

.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}

.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(209deg);
}

.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(212deg);
}

.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(223deg);
}

.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
}

.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(234deg);
}

.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(238deg);
}

.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(241deg);
}

.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(248deg);
}

.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(256deg);
}

.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(259deg);
}

.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(263deg);
}

.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(266deg);
}

.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(274deg);
}

.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(277deg);
}

.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(281deg);
}

.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(284deg);
}

.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}

.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(292deg);
}

.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(295deg);
}

.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(299deg);
}

.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
}

.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(306deg);
}

.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(310deg);
}

.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(313deg);
}

.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(317deg);
}

.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(320deg);
}

.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(328deg);
}

.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(331deg);
}

.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(335deg);
}

.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(338deg);
}

.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(342deg);
}

.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(346deg);
}

.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(349deg);
}

.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(353deg);
}

.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(356deg);
}

.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<p><b>These Are My Progess Bars</b></p>
<div class="progress-circle p10">
  <span>10%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle p33">
  <span>33%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p66">
  <span>66%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p77">
  <span>77%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p99">
  <span>99%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p100">
  <span>100%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
<div class="first50-bar"></div>
<div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you represent the rotation degree if we are looking for a progress past 50%?

Comment: another half circle needs to be used. and painted. edited with all deg.

Comment: I see. I think I'll be able to create it myself. Thank you for your help Hash.

Comment: how would you change the thickness of the progress bar in this?